# Check if a taxonomy Group exists by name in C#?

Tags: 2013, development, taxonomy

I am using the Managed Metadata Service and I want to check if a group under a specific `TermStore` already exists.

I tried the following code but I get an error (see below):

```
string siteCollectionUrl = "http://sp2013/sites/mytax";
SPSite site = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl);
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores[0];

Group termGroup = termStore.Groups["MYT"]

if (termGroup != null)
{
    ...
```

At the following line the error occurs:

```
Group termGroup = termStore.Groups["MYT"]
```

The error message is:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index

I want check if the group exist and if not, I want to create the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably want to use `taxonomySession.DefaultKeywordsTermStore` instead of `taxonomySession.TermStores[0]`

This is how you check if a group exists:

```
if (!termStore.Groups.Any(g => g.Name == "MYT"))
{
   termStore.CreateGroup("MYT");
   //you can specify a GUID if needed: 
   //termStore.CreateGroup("MYT", new Guid("{46D4495B-37B5-4313-B8B9-43F7E99E3028}"));
}
```

Comment: And thanks a lot for the hint on "taxonomySession.DefaultKeywordsTermStore"